# Java data encapsulation, initializing and postconditions?

Tags: java, encapsulation, post-conditions

My assignment is to complete the Date class shown below. The Date class encapsulates a date by storing the month, day, and year in private instance variables.

```
  public class Date
  {
  // declare your instance variables here
  // postcondition: instance variables are initialized with any valid values
  // you choose
  public Date ()
  {

  }
  // postcondition: instance variables are initialized with the given values if they are valid
  // the month instance variable should be between 1-12
  // the day instance variable should be between 1-31
  // if the parameters are not valid, the instance variables are given different values that are valid
  public Date(int theMonth, int theDay, int theYear)
  {
  }
  // postcondition: returns a String in the form month/day/year
  public String toString()
  {
  }
}
```

**The code below is what I have so far.** Frankly, I am pretty confused about what I am supposed to do, and I don't have an instructor to ask. The output is " 2/2/0 "

EDIT UPDATE: If I enter a year that is invalid, such as 200, it does not print the error message... My intention with the if statement was to catch errors where the year is not 4 digits. Is this correct? Thank you for any and all help!

```
public class Date
{
// declare your instance variables here
private int myMonth;
private int myDay; 
private int myYear;
// postcondition: instance variables are initialized with any valid values

// you choose
public Date ()
{
    myMonth = 11;
    myDay = 11;
    myYear = 2011;
}
// postcondition: instance variables are initialized with the given values if they are valid
// the month instance variable should be between 1-12
// the day instance variable should be between 1-31
// if the parameters are not valid, the instance variables are given different values that are valid
public Date(int theMonth, int theDay, int theYear)
{
   if ( theMonth >= 1 && theMonth <= 12 ) {
       myMonth = theMonth;
   }
   else {
       System.out.print("Month Value invalid; default to 1");
       myMonth = 1;
   }
   if( theDay >= 1 && theDay <= 31 ) {
       myDay = theDay;
   }
   else {
       System.out.print("Day Value invalid; default to 1");
       myDay = 1;
   }
   if( theYear < 4 ) {
       System.out.print("Year Value invalid; default to 2000");
       myYear = 2000;
   }
   else {
   myYear = theYear;
   }
}
   // postcondition: returns a String in the form month/day/year
public String toString()
{
    return myMonth + "/" + myDay + "/" + myYear;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int theMonth, theDay, theYear;
    theMonth = 2;
    theDay = 2;
    theYear = 200;
    Date date = new Date(theMonth, theDay, theYear);
    date.toString();
    System.out.println(date);
}
}
```

Comment: You never set `myYear` value to `theYear` value in your constructor if it's `>= 4`. It should be `if( theYear < 4 ) {
       System.out.print("Year Value invalid; default to 2000");
       myYear = 2000;
   } else {
    myYear = theYear;
   }`

Comment: The post-condition requirements do not call for the year to be validated at all, so you do not need to check if it's four digits or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind! When you call `date.toString();` you aren't *converting* the entire `date` variable into a `String`; since that doesn't actually change anything in the object, that line does nothing.

Fortunately it still works since when you call `println(date)` with the `PrintStream` object `System.out`, you are actually calling the variation of `println()` that takes an `Object` as a parameter instead of the one that takes a `String`, and what *that* does is get the result of the parameter's `toString()` method and prints that. So, it's the exact same result in the end.

**The real problem is in your constructor method.** Look really closely, and read through it. Pretend you are the parameter `theYear` and your value is 2222. At what point are you going to be used, and how?

---

**spoilers below, seriously go look**

---

You are in fact never setting the field `myYear` to *anything* unless the parameter `theYear` is invalid! The best solution here would be to add that missing `else` clause after you check `theYear` to match up with your handling of the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Your description of what is happening with the PrintStream was very informative. I have added that else statement now, so that is fixed :) But if I enter a year that is invalid, such as 200, it does not print the error message... My intention with the if statement was to catch errors where the year is not 4 digits. Is this correct?

Comment: @ReneaS. Ah! Actually what you are doing is checking to see if the year is less than 4. As in, the actual number 4. If it were 5 it would feel the year is absolutely fine, but if it were 2 or -394 it would replace it. What you want to test is if `theYear` is a 4 digit number... that is, any number between 1000 and 9999. So, just replace `theYear < 4` with `theYear < 1000 || theYear > 9999`, or whatever range you desire.

Comment: okay! Could you explain a little but why you used OR instead of AND?

Comment: @ReneaS. You are testing to see if the year is _invalid_ with this `if` statement. You want it to set it to a default value if `theYear` is too small OR it is too large; if you put `&&` there, it would always accept the value because it cannot be too large AND too small at the same time.

Comment: I see now, thanks! So theYear > 1000 && theYear < 9999 would test to see if it was valid then? And I should change the other statements also since my directions were to check if invalid, right?

Comment: The reverse of `theYear < 1000 || theYear > 9999` is actually `theYear >= 1000 && theYear <= 9999`. Remember, the inverse of `<` is `>=` not `>`! And it's always good to double-check your conditions. Some good advice: If you are going to have an `if` statement for every parameter, make sure that you are checking for either a **good** or a **bad** value *the same* for all your parameters. Nothing is more confusing than seeing 3 checks for `if (condition) /*invalid*/; else /*valid*/;` followed by the opposite `if (condition) /*valid*/; else /*invalid*/;`. Organize your thoughts and be consistent

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix your implementation in several places:

- Since you are learning about encapsulation, you should declare your variables `private`
- Assuming that there are no other methods in your class, you should also declare your variables `final`
- There is no rule asking to validate the year, so the `if` condition needs to go; assignment of the year needs to be unconditional

This should fix the problem with printing zero instead of the year.

Note: (skip this if you have *not* studied exceptions yet) a common way to deal with ensuring post-conditions in the constructor is throwing exceptions when the parameters are invalid, rather than trying to guess what these parameters should have been. Consider throwing [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when you detect that one of the arguments is not valid:

```
public Date(int theMonth, int theDay, int theYear)
{
   if ( theMonth < 1 || theMonth > 12 ) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("month");
   }
   if( theDay < 1 || theDay > 31 ) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("day");
   }
   myMonth = theMonth;
   myDay = theDay;
   myYear = theYear;
}
```

Comment: Chances are Renea is not yet at the point where they are learning about Exceptions and standard practice. The assignment most likely requires them to set default values, so I wouldn't worry about that for now.

Comment: @Widdershins That's a fair observation, I added a note saying that OP should ignore the note about exceptions if they have not studied the topic yet.